# The usage of string::reserve

Tags: c++, string

When is it appropriate to use `string::reserve`?
I realize that it is used to reserve a certain amount of characters for the string to hold but  how can this be useful? Does the string still resize if you go over? Does it add a level of efficiency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will "reserve" the specified space to reduce the number of reallocations. If you have a good idea of how big the string will get, then reserving that amount of space should prevent any reallocation.

If you go over, it will resize, but the idea is to reduce the number of reallocations.

Comment: It's sort of like `char str[50] = 'my string';`, except wrapped in the string container, with a mechanism to still re-allocate if you go longer than 50 characters (and all the other utilities that come with the string class).

Comment: It will also reduce fragmentation of the heap. If you allocate and free a lot of strings using a fixed size that is usually big enough will mean that block can be easily reused by the next string to come along after the first string is freed.

Comment: Should we reserve 1 more to anticipate a "null terminated" string?